# How to make different transition for "hide" compared its"show"

Tags: html, css, css-transitions

Suppose I have toggle function which make animation on `height` , `width` and `opacity` of a `div` -

```
transition: width 2s, height 2s , opacity 2s,transform 2s;
```

Here is its demo - jsFiddle

When it change from hide to show all these 3 attribute got animation  ,

Now , I want to apply on it hiding (from show to hide) just animation on its opacity such that it disappear by becoming from `opacity : 1` to `opacity : 0` (with no `height , width` change)  - [like this - jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/urielz/otnbk153/) .

**Update :**

I want to make the "show to hide" of the 1st jsFiddle as the "show to hide" of the 2nd jsFiddle without to change the "hide to show" of the 1st hsFiddle .

How to get it ?

Comment: Your fiddle code looks different from what you've showed in question. Am I seeing something wrong somewhere?

Comment: I can see only 1 fiddle link

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve that by using [CSS Transform scale](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_2dtransforms.asp).

You can apply that on your toggle function().

like this:

```
$('.testDiv').css({
    '-webkit-transform': 'scale(1)',
    '-moz-transform': 'scale(1)',
    '-o-transform': 'scale(1)'
});
```

and to revert:

```
$('.testDiv').css({
    '-webkit-transform': 'scale(0)',
    '-moz-transform': 'scale(0)',
    '-o-transform': 'scale(0)'
});
```

**[jsFIDDLE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/otnbk153/2/)**

Comment: but I want no height or width changing in the revert , just on the opacity .

Comment: Just remove the script on the part you dont want the scaling to take place